# Obtener el ultimo Id registrado en mysql NO EL MAYOR

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

yo necesito encontrar el ultimo id para un numero de folio tipo 0000/YEAR donde si  el año cambia los 4 digitos empiezar de nuevo desde 0001 use el MAX pero si habiendo un cambio de año si se reinicia pero al segundo registro que se ingrese tomaria el mayo del año pasado por ejemplo digamos que en el 2018 fue 0100/2018 al inicio del 2019 tomaria 0001/2019 pero cuando sea el 0002/2019 en lugar de eso tomaria 0101/2019

```
using (MySqlConnection Mysqlcon = new MySqlConnection(conectionString))
        {
            anio.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");
            codigo.Text = "CODIGO";
            //anio.Text = "2000";
                Mysqlcon.Open();
            MySqlCommand mySqlCmd2 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT MAX(idPrueba),MAX(anio) FROM prueba", Mysqlcon);
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(mySqlCmd2);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
           int id = Convert.ToInt32(row["LAST_INSERT_ID(idPrueba)"]);
           int aniodb = Convert.ToInt32(row["MAX(anio) "]);
           int suma = int.Parse(anio.Text);

            if (suma==aniodb)
            {
                idPrueba1.Text = row["MAX(idPrueba)"].ToString();
                anioBD.Text = row["MAX(anio)"].ToString();
            }
            if (suma > aniodb)
            {
                idPrueba1.Text = "0";
                anioBD.Text = anio.Text;
            }
        }
```

EN ESTE CODIGO SIEMPRE ESTARA TOMANDO EL NUMERO MAYOR SIN IMPORTAR EL AÑO QUE SEA, NECESITO QUE ESTE TOMANDO  EL ULTIMO ID

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Donde esta el codigo que intentas obtener? lo que necesitas es max, pero una conjuncion de max en el mismo campo separado en dos...

Comment: ¿No hay una columna `DATETIME` en esa tabla que guarde la fecha completa?

Comment: El query no debería ser algo así?:  SELECT MAX(idPrueba) FROM prueba WHERE anio=?

Comment: Johan Donado B. es que el que pusiste de  anio=? – es para insertar no y lo que necesito es obtener ese numero a un campo de texto y mostrarlo, sin enviarlo

Comment: fecha completa_ solo requiero el año que se ingreso para tener el folio que requiero

Comment: Si hay una columna `DATETIME`, no veo por qué incluyes el año también en esa columna, basta que pongas el número secuencial y luego haces un `ORDER BY columnaFecha, folio`. Será todo más simple y evitarás guardar información redundante.